# dart 0.8.7&Bootstrap.js - Chromium crashes when I click on any element

Tags: dart, twitter-bootstrap-3, chromium, dart-polymer

chromium crashes after updating the dart to version 0.8.7.

Please see the following code:

1. Custom element:

```html
<polymer-element name="custom-elm">
      <template>
        <div class="container">
          <article>
            <content>
              <!-- PAGE CONTENT HERE -->
            </content>
          </article>
        </div>
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="custom_elm.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>

<!-- language-all: dart -->
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
@CustomTag('custom-elm')
class CustomElement extends PolymerElement {

  bool get applyAuthorStyles => true;

  CustomElement.created() : super.created() {    
  }
}
```

1. Index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>index page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap 3, jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

    <link rel="import" href="custom_elm.html">
  </head>
  <body>

  <custom-elm>
    <!-- some page content -->

    <input id="nickname" class="form-control" placeholder="Some input"/>

    <!-- some page content -->
  </custom-elm>

  <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


<!-- language-all: dart -->
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
void main() {
  initPolymer();
}
```

The dartium crashes when I mouse click on the input. What's wrong? 
Note that this code works if I do not use the script bootstrap.min.js (Bootstrap 3).

Comment: the same error in the latest version of Polymer 0.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this issue on code.google.com http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14611